# REPORT RDLC: I have a String parameter in a DataSet in VS 2010 C# but after executing query, nothing shows up

Tags: string, reporting-services, parameters, report, rdlc

**I am making a Report using RDLC. Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate + SQL Server 2012 Express**

> **InvoiceID is a String.** This is a query with parameter on a Dataset TableAdapter. I entered this SQL in the Query Builder part of the DataSet.

```
SELECT        SequenceNo, InvoiceID, VisitID, CaseNo, WalkinID, Payment, Invoice_date, Status
FROM            INVOICE
WHERE        (InvoiceID = @InvoiceID)
```

When I click the Execute Query in the Query Builder, it asks for a value. I enter 20130508-650875. No quotes whatsoever. Then it produces the result I wanted.

Now, I'm going to run the program then generate the report.

The C# part:

```
 INVOICETableAdapter.Fill(dataset.INVOICE, InvoiceID);
    MessageBox.Show(InvoiceID.ToString()); //just to confirm what value the parameter is getting
```

Now, nothing comes out of the table in my report. I don't know why. The table on my report now only contains the headers of the columns I dragged.

I TRIED REMOVING THE ---WHERE--- PART OF THE QUERY AND IT PRODUCED A LOT OF RESULTS!

```
SELECT        SequenceNo, InvoiceID, VisitID, CaseNo, WalkinID, Payment, Invoice_date, Status
FROM            INVOICE
//WHERE        (InvoiceID = @InvoiceID)
```

Now, I want to ask you guys what could be the reason why does the table in my report go blank when I execute the report with parameters. But if it has no parameters, it produces all results. Could it be the query?

Comment: Nevermind, I just used VisitID, which is int, as the parameter. There is really some issue when making a String as a parameter in the Query Builder that I don't really know :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's obviously the query, but probably not as sinister an issue as you're expecting.  First step should be ensuring that the parameter is your query is *actually getting set*.  With the information provided here, it sounds like your where clause is filtering out all rows, so either the parameter is remaining null, or it's not being set to what you expected.

Try having your code print out the entire query/sproc call, grab exactly what it spits out, and run that manually.